I want to delete the content when I click on the button
from kivy.app import App
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SecondScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.mass_lbl = Label(text="Введите свой вес, кг:")
        self.mass_input = TextInput(font_size=20)
        
        self.grow_lbl1 = Label(text="Введите свой рост, см:")
        self.grow_input = TextInput(font_size=20)
        
        self.result_lbl2 = Label(text="Ваш ИМТ равен:")
        self.result_input = TextInput(text="")    
        btn2 = Button(text='Очистить',
                           on_press=self.delete_bmi)
    def delete_bmi(self, instance, touch):
        try:
            self.mass_input.text = " "
            self.grow_input.text = " "
            self.result_input.text = " "
        except FileNotFoundError:
              pass

I tried only 1 method as .text = "" in my code.
Other methods I have not yet figured out how to use

There's no question here.

Why do you have except FileNotFoundError? Nothing in that code tries to use a file.
